# Phonegap application issue

Tags: cordova

I'm developing an app that on timeout update some data on db and consequently change view on page relative to data. The app works perfectly on chrome and firefox but when it run on device this data doesn't update but on db is update. Maybe memory cache problem?
This line maybe has error?Maybe "$(window)"?

```
current_user.Set_last_activity();
$(window).bind('onload',setInterval(function(){current_user.Set_last_activity();},5000));
this.check_users_online() ;
$(window).bind('onload', setInterval(function(){self.check_users_online();},5000));
```

in logcat was appeared this error:

```
08-20 00:12:57.023: E/SUMAN-statusbarpolicy(1658):     
<!>com.android.systemui.statusbar.policy.StatusBarPolicy 1069<!>  
mServiceState.getRoaming()false
```

Comment: A code sample would help us debug. Is the app running in the foreground or backgorund when the update is supposed to happen?

Comment: How can I check if it's in foreground or backgorund?

Comment: The app when I've tested it was always on the screen..

Comment: That would means it's running in the foreground. JavaScript in Cordova apps don't run when the app is in the background, which is why I asked. Do you have any code sample of the problem this problem? Is there any way you can validate that the request from your app makes it to your service? Is the host that your service runs on whitelisted?

Comment: I'm using parse.com...I can't copy all code is too long...I add two rows code that call on timeout a function..maybe is here the problem?

Comment: Did you whitelist *.parse.com?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know what is whitelist...

Comment: From Cordova's documentation http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide

Comment: in my config.xml there is: <access origin="*"/>, I think is ok or I must add specific for parse?

Answer (score 0):

Cordova applications need to declare what URLs they plan to pull data from. This list of known host names is the "whitelist".

Your browser may be more flexible but Cordova needs the whitelist entry.

Here is the [documentation on adding a domain to your whitelist](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide).

=Edit=

Try binding to the `deviceready` event instead of the `onload` event.

Comment: in my config.xml there is: <access origin="*"/>, I think is ok or I must add specific for parse?

Comment: That should be sufficient to access any domain. As I suggest in my edited answer try binding to deviceready instead of onload.

Comment: I've tried with deviceready but doesn't work maybe is $(window)?

Comment: I don't know what would be wrong with $(window), but since you've tried deviceready, I'm out of ideas for you at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for help me...it's very strange how on browser works perfectly and on device no...